# Is there any compensation or financial aid for essential workers who died from COVID-19?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, covid-19, death

My mom was an essential worker (production plant) and contracted COVID-19 in July 2020 and died from it in August 2020. Her work required symptomatic people with no PTO to report to work or be terminated. They denied her claim to file for unemployment and workers comp and said she could only file for disability payments, which is 2/3rds her pay, and then cut off her payment the day she died. She has a house with a mortgage on it.

Is there any way to get compensation for her death or aid in paying off her mortgage?

Comment: I'm very sorry for your loss. I've tried to clean up the question to make it more answerable for this site.

Comment: Laws vary by region, what country/state does this pertain to?

Comment: Do you need to pay off her mortgage?

Comment: This is in Coon Rapids, Minnesota

Comment: Yes we had to pay off her mortgage in January.